# Display div if category has a specific parent

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a PHP snippet that displays a div on product pages based on their specific category ID.

How can I adapt this code to display the div based on whether the category is an ancestor of a specific parent?

I'd like to take a more blanket approach as opposed to singling out specific IDs if possible - here's what I've been using so far (thank you in advance for any help):

```
function options_available() {
    global $product;
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        break;
    }
    if ($product_cat_id == "54" || $product_cat_id == "84" || $product_cat_id == "2022" || $product_cat_id == "56" || $product_cat_id == "972" || $product_cat_id == "55" || $product_cat_id == "62" || $product_cat_id == "63" || $product_cat_id == "2024" || $product_cat_id == "2023" || $product_cat_id == "61" || $product_cat_id == "2210" || $product_cat_id == "2253" ) {
       echo '<div class="fkrow">  </div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'options_available', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: You might like to look up `in_array()` so when you code something like this next time you can write it in a clear and concise way

Comment: Why write a foreach loop and then break after the first occurance is seen?

Comment: _“based on whether the category is an ancestor of a specific parent”_ - so, a – grandparent?  (Or grand-grand-…-parent, respectively.) Or are you confusing ancestor and descendant here?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - it's a slightly modified piece of someone else's code, and I have to admit it is certainly clunky - your suggestion is duly noted, thank you

Comment: @CBroe I have two or three parent categories, and if any of the subcategories are children of one of those specified parent categories, that's when i'd like to show the content.

Comment: Still rather unclear / ambiguous. What does “any of” the subcategories mean here? Does that mean sibling categories on the same level, or are we talking nested hierarchy at this point? Mind showing an example of the category structure, and explain at which point of that we “are” here?

Comment: So for example :

Digital Pianos is the parent category - within in it are Yamaha Pianos, Korg Pianos, and Used Pianos - within those subcategories are several other subcategories.

I'm trying to show a div/span/whatever on product pages if the product is a descendant of one of the parent categories, so i don't have to list all of the subcategories those products are in separately.

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a method of combining both parent and subcategory queries within an elseif statement.

The following displays only if the product exists in a specific parent category (with !exceptions for some subcategories):

```
function test($term) {
global $product;
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ($terms as $term) {
$product_cat_id = $term->term_id;

    if ( $term->parent == 60 && $product_cat_id !== 365 ) 
{
    echo '<div class="uptxt"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><a href="/used-digital-pianos"> Save money: Buy a preowned model</a></div>';}


elseif ( $term->parent == 50 && $product_cat_id !== 64 ) 
{
    echo '<div class="uktxt"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><a href="/used-keyboards"> Save money: Buy a preowned model</a></div>';}
}

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'test', 25);
```